# uninstall .net core sdk 1.x on remote machines

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, .net-core, azure-search-.net-sdk

Need to uninstall .net sdk older version on remote machines.[pop up window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leoOf.png) is showing up when tried below PowerShell script to uninstall older .net sdk version. So .net core sdk is not uninstalling in remote windows machines without user input.

```
If
(Test-Path "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.1.14")
{
Start-Process -FilePath $env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/X{BCB0834B-EC91-4237-AF17-A2F67FC93796}"
}
```

tried adding /quite

```
Start-Process -FilePath $env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/X{BCB0834B-EC91-4237-AF17-A2F67FC93796} /quiet" but not working 
[with quite option][2]as well
```

Comment: You're saying without, but you actually want to use it? `Msiexec.exe /X{BCB0834B-EC91-4237-AF17-A2F67FC93796} /quiet`

Comment: my concern is to uninstall .net sdk automatically by script on remote machines without user input.

Comment: try `/quiet /qn`. (qn --> no UI)

Answer (score 0):

$arguments = "/quiet"

Start-Process -FilePath $env:systemroot\system32\msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/X{BCB0834B-EC91-4237-AF17-A2F67FC93796}

Comment: facing same issue. pop up window is showing after adding  $arguments = "/quiet"